# How to cover with tests a simple Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am trying to cover with tests a very simple Apex trigger, but with no luck. 0% of code is covered.

Here's the trigger:

```
trigger AssignPricebookToOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert) {
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = Trigger.new;
    for (Opportunity o : opportunities) {
        o.Pricebook2Id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

EDIT:

Here's the Test Class (Tests pass, but code is not covered)

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
public with sharing class AssignPricebookToOpportunityTriggerTest {
    static testMethod void testAssignPricebookToOpportunity(){
        test.startTest();

        Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
        o.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
        o.StageName = 'In Qualification';
        o.CloseDate = Date.today();

        insert o;
        test.stopTest();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the test code that you aren't having luck with?

Comment: What is the test class that you have written to try and get coverage? It should insert an Opportunity, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a dedicated mutate class and pass in your list of opportunities and then write the test around that class/method. Should get the coverage and it also keeps your trigger clean.

for example:

```
public with sharing class OppMutator
{
   public static void ApplyDataToOpps(List<sObject>inOpps)
   {
      List<Opportunity> opportunities = (List<Opportunities>)inOpps;
      for (Opportunity o : opportunities) 
      {
        o.Pricebook2Id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
      }
   }
}

trigger AssignPricebookToOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert) 
{
   OppMutator.ApplyDataToOpps(Trigger.new);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but same thing again - 0%

Comment: Can you post up some code? That may help.